# json_encode with large strings

Tags: php

I'm returning a html response in  a json object field `$o->sHtml`.

The testing `sHtml` is about 13000 characters and after `json_encode` its `$o->sHtml = null`. 
Any idea why?

Comment: How are you declaring that? Can you show it?

Answer (score 4):

Json encode only works with UTF-8 encoded data. check whether your input data is utf8 or not

```
$json  = json_encode($o->sHtml); //or json_encode($o);
$error = json_last_error();
var_dump($json, $error === JSON_ERROR_UTF8);
```

These are the possible errors

```
JSON_ERROR_NONE -   No error has occurred    
JSON_ERROR_DEPTH -  The maximum stack depth has been exceeded    
JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH - Invalid or malformed JSON    
JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR -Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded  
JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX - Syntax error     
JSON_ERROR_UTF8 -   Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
```

ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php